# Get the point value from NSPoint array in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I do have a array with NSPoints. How do I get the first element value from that array

Comment: Show us what you've tried.  How is the array declared?

Answer (score 0):

`[nsarray objectAtIndex:0]` if it's an `NSArray`,

`array[0]` if it's a plain C array. Not that hard, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

With such little information, I can only guess your declarations.

```
NSPoint *point = [arrayInstance objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: If you use `ARC` you get compilcation error in this case because need use cast `(__bridge NSPoint *)` or call `CFBridgeRetain()`. For storing `NSPoint` in array best solution is wrapping it in `NSValue`